# Splitting a string in bat files or batch script

Tags: batch-file

I would like to split a `key=value` pair that is read from a file and assign the them to two respective values. However when I try doing that I am not able to set the value to a variable, the value is set to blank instead of the value.

The file has:

```
x1=y1 
x2=y2 
x3=y3
```

Here is my sample code:

```
FOR /f "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%a IN (%%~nxi) DO (
ECHO "Begin for"
     ECHO %%a
     ECHO %%b
     set key=%%a
     ECHO key=%key%
     set val=%%b
     ECHO val=%val%
ECHO "End for"
    )
```

Expected Output:

```
    Begin for
    x1
    y1
    key=x1
    value=y1
    End for
    Begin for
    x2
    y2
    key=x2
    value=y1
    End for
```

The initial `ECHO` statements are successful but the `SET` and `Echo` for the new variable are returning "" blank.

Actual Output:

```
    Begin for
    x1
    y1
    *key=
    value=*
    End for
    Begin for
    x2
    y2
    *key=
    value=*
    End for
```

Answer (score 2):

When a line or a block of code (the code enclosed in parenthesis in your `for`, `if`, ... ) is reached, the parser removes all variable reads, replacing them with the value inside the variable before the line/block starts to execute. So, if the value of a variable is changed inside a line/block, this changed value is not visible inside that same line/block since all access to the variable content has been replaced with its value.

So, if the value of the variable is changed inside a line/block AND the changed value of the variable needs to be read/accessed inside the same line/block, delayed expansion is needed.

When delayed expansion is enabled, the access to the value in variables can change it usual syntax `%var%` into `!var!`, asking the parser to not remove the read with the value until the code is executed. It is not necessary to replace all variable reads, just the reads of values changed in the same block.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions 

    FOR /f "tokens=1,2* delims==" %%a IN (%%~nxi) DO (
        ECHO "Begin for"
        ECHO %%a
        ECHO %%b

        set "key=%%a"
        set "val=%%b"

        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

        ECHO key=!key!
        ECHO val=!val!

        endlocal

        ECHO "End for"
    )

    ECHO key=%key%
    ECHO val=%val%
```